# Error with list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new to single line for loops and don't seem to get the gist.

I'm trying to create a four element sized list with random integers from 0 to 9. However when I run the code it returns nothing

Can anybody please explain to me how to work with single line for loops?

```
def create_code(código):
    creator =  [código.append(random.randint(0, 10)) for index in range(0,4)]
    return creator #this returns empty
```

Comment: You mean "list comprehensions", try searching for that

Comment: why do you have a special char: ó? Does that even work

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did, i realize the question isn't well put, but as far as i get it. List comprehensions work as such: [thing for thing in lis_of_things]

Comment: Then what precisely is the problem? That's what you've got, but it's full of None and you don't appear to return it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i've edited the question. The problem was it wasn't returning anything

Comment: A list comprehension should not be used like a drop-in replacement for a for-loop. Do not use it for side-effects.

Comment: @MiguelLuís that is impossible, python functions *always* return *something*. So, either you were getting a list full of `None`s or an empty list. Either way, the problem stems from you using a list-comprehension where you really just want a for-loop.

Comment: For python >= 3.6, there's: `random.choices(range(10), k=4)`.

Answer (score 4):

Skip the append inside the loop, try

```
creator = [random.randint(0, 10) for index in range(0,4)]
```

Then if you need to this can be used to extend the input list:

```
código.extend(creator)
```

Comment: I tried it and  returned: TypeError: create_code() missing 1 required positional argument: 'codigo'

Comment: @MiguelLuís this is a different issue now. Please accept the answer & move on with debugging the rest of your code.

Comment: note that `for index in range(0,4)` could be `for _ in range(4)`